# Monitor problem while installing linux mint on a old Fujitsu laptop

Tags: linux-mint, graphics

I was installing linux mint on a old laptop that had windows 10 (32bit) but calmed to support 64 bit.

I made a bootable flash drive and boot it up. When it started booting it was doing it for a long time, and I noticed some part of the screen got dark. I turned off the pc and booted windows 10 as normal and part of the screen was still black.

[image]

The laptop has:

- Intel core 2 duo CPU (T6570)
- 4GB ram
- 32-bit operating system, x64-based processor
- NVIDIA GeForce 8200M G